# Improve board game turn processing

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a fairly simple board game i've been building in C++.  Currently, players are assigned a player number (1, 2, 3...N) depending on the number of players in the game.  Pretty standard.  The players and their stats are kept in a file which include their name and their number.  I then process turns via reading a directory with turn files.  The turns are submitted by the players and contain only their player name and their task/turn.  In the future, I plan to have player numbers change so to mix up the order of the game.

(if you're a board gamer, think Caylus or Agricola)

Players are read in at the start of the application.  I then give a command and turns are processed.  Basically, I simply read the directory of turns, 1 by 1, and match that turn to a player name.  As it stands, there is no order in turn processing.  Player 3 can go before player 2.

I figured this wasn't a great design so I came up with the following solution:

- As I'm comparing which turn goes with which player, insert that turn into a `std::map<int, Turn>`, the key being the player number.
- After I gather all the turns, search for player N, starting with 1, within the map and process his turn.

  - I'm iterating through the list of players again here because I need to match the player with the player number in order to process the turn.
- Do this until I've processed all players.

Is there a better way to do this?  This seems kludgey and a lot of overhead.

Thanks!

Note: My turn processing method takes in a `Player class` (which represents the player stats file) and a `struct` representing the turn read from the turn file.

Comment: Given the small number of players, iterating over a simple array-type is probably good enough.  Complicated structures tend to be slower than their primitive counterparts in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think of defining an Action class for a player acting in his turn, which is defined by a player number and a turn number, and define a comparison on this class. Read all Actions from the files, insert them into an ordered list, and then process these actions.

Comment: I think I might go this route.  I can create a simple sort function for the vector based on player num and process the turn loaded into that player.

Answer (score 2):

So as I understand it, your problem is you have thee bits of linked data: `Turn`s, `PlayerID`s and `PlayerTurnPosition`s (OK the latter 2 are ints but I'll assume you've typedef-ed them to something like that to avoid confusion).  And you want to maintain a lookup from the PlayerID and PlayerTurnPosition values to the corresponding Turn, and also maintain a bidirectional relation between the Player info.

This is just screaming out to use a [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) with some extra info attached to each pair relation; something like

```
boost::bimaps::bimap< 
    boost::bimaps::vector_of<PlayerID>, 
    boost::bimaps::vector_of<PlayerTurnPosition>, 
    boost::bimaps::with_info<boost::shared_ptr<Turn> > 
  >
```

should do the job nicely (although there are other options for the left/right view container types; `set_of` probably makes more sense given playerIDs and positions are presumably unique).

Example of this sort of `with_info` usage [in the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/example/tutorial_info_hook.cpp).

Comment: great time to try out the bimap!  Thanks tim!

Comment: Hmm actually the bimap might not get me to where I want.  There is a 4th piece of data, and this is the Player status data.  This might be poor design on my part.

Comment: Well if you only need to go from PlayerID to PlayerStatus, can't that just be stored in another table ?  Of course if you really do need to lookup from player status to player ID... well there's always boost::multi_index - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html - which is the generalization of bimap.  It's considerably more fiddly to use though (IMHO).